# Surveys of Goodwillie Calculus 

Tags: soft-question, reference-request, ct.category-theory, calculus-of-functors, homotopy-theory

Is there a good general introduction to Goodwillie calculus out there, like a paper or publication that gives a general overview of the calculus as well as how it is useful and why we are interested in it (especially with regards to stable homotopy theory)?

Or perhaps I might say, while I am reading Goodwillie's Calculus I, is there another paper out there that is introductory, perhaps with a long preface or introduction with intuitive ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, for completeness, I will add Nicholas Kuhn's paper relating calculus of functors to chromatic homotopy theory: http://www.math.rochester.edu/u/faculty/doug/otherpapers/KuhnKinosaki.pdf

Comment: Goodwillie and Weiss have some nice survey papers for embedding calculus.  Calculus of Embedddings Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. 33 (1996), 177-187. Embeddings from the point of view of immersion theory, Part I Geom. and Topology 3 (1999), 67-101. Spaces of smooth embeddings, disjunction and surgery, in Surveys on Surgery Theory vol. 2, Princeton University Press (2001), eds. Cappell, Ranicki and Rosenberg.  They're all embedding calculus, though.  

Comment: There is a preprint version of "Caclculus I" which existed before the published version that gives a lot of intuition behind the ideas in its long introduction. The published version of "Calculus I is quite different. (By the way, Ryan, I am a co-author of the last reference ;-).)

Comment: Jon, I second Nick Kuhn's notes regarding chromatic homotopy theory. I think they do a great job of laying out the framework for Goodwillie Calculus.

Comment: Hi John, yes, after I wrote that I noticed I missed mentioning you.  :)  I've enjoyed reading your paper, BTW, and I wish MO had an edit feature for comments.  Also, JonB, if you can get a copy of Goodwillie's dissertation, I find pages 1 through about 29 to be quite informative.  Although the dissertation does not have the full formalism of calculus, it's nice to see how it originated in its "native" environment.  The dissertation is AMS Memoirs Number 431.  July 1990, Vol 86 (first of two). 

Comment: Ryan, no problem. For comments, I usually copy text into my clipboard before I post it. That way if I need to modify the comment I can delete it, copy it back into a new comment frame and then modify it.

Comment: @Ryan thanks, I think I can get that at the library here.

Comment: The link to Nicholas Kuhn's paper mentioned above is now broken, but I'm guessing it corresponds to this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0410342

Comment: @John  Could you let me know the title of the preprint you mentioned in the comment? It sounds very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @John BTW, Is there a concrete example where embedding calculus could be used to produce exotic embeddings?

Comment: @user8749 Not that I am aware of.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like the [nLab article](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Goodwillie+calculus) is pretty nice.  There you'll find a list of references, including this:

> Brian Munson, Introduction to the manifold calculus of Goodwillie-Weiss, [arXiv:1005.1698](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.1698)

Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Wow these are great resources, thanks! I like this bit from Munson's paper:

"We will frequently omit arguments which we find distract us from our attempts to be lighthearted."

Right up my alley.  

Comment: :-) That's a good bit of honest writing.

Answer (score 10):

This is 7 years too late, but this survey (to appear in the Handbook of Homotopy Theory) is a really readable survey of Goodwillie calculus: https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.00803.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a pretty good birds-eye view by reading this 2004 Oberwolfach report (no. 17):

http://www.mfo.de/document/0414/OWR_2004_17.pdf

Calculus of Functors is the theme of the 2012 Talbot workshop, and one can hope that there will be reasonable attempts made to collect introductory and expository material and make it available. There may be much better answers to your question in a month or two (written 1/23/2012).

Comment: As a shameless plug, I think Greg gives a pretty streamlined overview, with (detailed) references (including sections numbers of papers) here: http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/2012/2012TalbotTalks.pdf . 

Comment: I guess the notes from the 2012 Talbot workshop are now found here http://math.mit.edu/conferences/talbot/index.php?year=2012&sub=talks

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good overview in "Cubical Homotopy Theory" chapter 10 which is available online [here](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/munson-volic.pdf)