# Categorification of the Taylor polynomial of a function at a point

Tags: soft-question, categorification

Can you give a categorification of the Taylor polynomial of a real function $ f : U \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by :
$$ f(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a) + \frac{1}{2} (x-a)^{2} + \dots + \dfrac{1}{n!} f^{(n)} (a) (x-a)^n + o (x^{n+1} ) $$
in a neighbourhood $ U $ of an element $ a \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What does 'categorification' mean for you? This is an important *idea* in contemporary mathematics, but is not a defined technical term. If you mean it broadly, this seems okay (to me), but I think this should be made clear, so that it does not look like a defined question relative to some formal system. (I recognize that you already tagged it a 'soft-question'; I am not criticizing.) Also "limited development" seems a very unusual term to me; this is usually taught as the 'Taylor polynomial" around $a$. Also, "element of $a$" does not make sense.

Comment: For me, categorification means a process which passes from a set to a category, or from a categorie to a $ 2 $ - category ... etc.

Comment: Look up "calculus of functors." It is a really spectacular categorification of Taylor series.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86464/surveys-of-goodwillie-calculus the references given here may also be helpful